# fullpage.js sticky header won't stick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I've got a problem with my sticky header not sticky in the fullpage.js environment.
I've got a site where I did get it to work but the way it worked can't be correct because it's full of errors and bad coded pieces.

Now Question is do I look at the css part for the fixed position or does my problem finds itself in the javascript.

Code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
var $window = $(window);
var nav = $('#main-navigation');
$window.scroll(function(){
    if ($window.scrollTop() >= 300) {
       nav.addClass('fixed-header');
    }
    else {
       nav.removeClass('fixed-header');
    }
});</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      $('#topnav ul li a').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var scrolldiv = $(this).attr('href');
        
        $(scrolldiv).animatescroll({padding:50});
      });
    });
    </script>
```

```css
@CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";
/* Reset CSS
 * --------------------------------------- */
body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,
form,fieldset,input,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
a{
 text-decoration:none;
}
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
}
fieldset,img {
    border: 0;
}
address,caption,cite,code,dfn,em,strong,th,var {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
strong{
 font-weight: bold;
}
ol,ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
caption,th {
    text-align: left;

}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    color:#444;
}
q:before,q:after {
    content:'';
}
abbr,acronym { border: 0;
}


/* Custom CSS
 * --------------------------------------- */
body{
 font-family: arial,helvetica;
 color: #333;
 color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.wrap{
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 width: 960px;
 position: fixed;
}
h1{
 font-size: 6em;
}
p{
 font-size: 2em;
}
.intro p{
 width: 50%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 font-size: 1.5em;
}
.section{
 text-align:center;
}



/*StickyHeaderNavigationMenu*/

header{position:fixed;bottom:0;z-index:99900; width:100%; 
}
.fixed{
  position: fixed;
  bottom:0; left:0;
  width: 100%;
  z-index:10000; }
.fixed-header {
  position:fixed;
  top:0px; left:0;
  width: 100%; 
}

nav {
  width:100%;
  height:60px;
  background:#36A8B5;
  postion:fixed;
  z-index:10000;
  bottom:0px;
  left:0;
}

nav ul { 
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-left:0;
  text-align:center;
  width:100%; 
}
nav ul li { 
  display: inline-block; 
  line-height: 60px;
  margin-left: 35px;
}
nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none; 
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
  <header>
     <div class="header">
    <nav id="main-navigation">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="./schools.html">Schools</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section1">Gallery</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section2">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section3">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section4">Snorkeling</a></li>
          <li><a href="#section5">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
            </div>
  </header>

<div id="fullpage">
 
 <div class="section " id="section0">
    <div class="layer2"></div>
    <div class="layer">
   <h1>Fixed elements</h1>
   <p>Create your own headers and footers</p>
  </div>
    
     <video autoplay loop muted controls id="myVideo">
   <source src="imgs/flowers.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="imgs/flowers.webm" type="video/webm">
  </video>
  
 </div>
 <div class="section" id="section1">
       <div class="slide"   id="slide1"> <h1>We provide the best high level snorkel gear for great value!</h1></div>
             <div class="slide"   id="slide2"></div>
             <div class="slide"   id="slide3"><h1>Make your own great experience and enjoy New Zealand’s unique underwater Sea Life!</h1></div>
             <div class="slide"   id="slide4"><h1>After a day on the beach, relax in our Garden Café and Restaurant and recharge your batteries with some awesome food to your liking. 
       Your adventure starts here!</h1></div>
             <div class="slide"   id="slide5"></div>
             <div class="slide"   id="slide6"><h1>
                Not a strong swimmer? – No worries, we offer:<br/>
                <ul style:"list-style-type:none">
       <li> 5 mm wetsuits – fitted to your needed size</li>
       <li> masks, snorkels, weight belts, fins</li>
       <li> optical masks available</li>
                </div>
             <div class="slide"   id="slide7"></div>
             <div class="slide"   id="slide8"></div>

 </div>
 <div class="section" id="section2">
  <div class="intro">
   <h1>Enjoy it</h1>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I've added other pieces of the side to show the hierarchy in the section and to make it scrollable.

Comment: Won't stick where? It's stuck to the bottom right now and moving it the top is just css.

Comment: that's just it on my other site it goes up and sticks there when scrolling in this it doesn't or maybe I'm clearly overseeing something.

Comment: Well if you change header's `bottom:0` to `top:0` that does that. Note that you need to adding padding due to the overlap.

Comment: Okay I see where it went wrong I should stick at the bottom but when I scroll down to the next section it  should stay at the top! The js script is should do that. 
Sticking it to the top or bottom is not a problem.

Comment: Anybody else knows what to do? Really can't get this to be fixed for some reason..